# Cut off when making graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hi everyone I want to ask if there is a way to fix the cut off when producing the graph in png files? I noticed when I review the file, there is a cutoff where I lable "reporting delay."

Does anyone know how to fix this? I would submit a photo but I do not have enough rep credits to post one.

Thank you!

```
ggplot(dcurve %>% filter(!is.na(D)),aes(x=D,y=N,label=N)) +  

  geom_rect(aes(xmin=(repdate-12.5), xmax=(repdate+1), ymin=0, ymax=maxn), fill="lightblue4", alpha=.01) + 

  geom_col(color="white") +  

  scale_x_date(date_labels="%b-%d", date_breaks = "5 day") + 

  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0), breaks=c(seq(0,maxn,25))) + 

  ylab("No. Confirmed and Probable Cases") + 

  xlab("Episode Date") + labs(subtitle=repdate, caption=cnote) + 

  theme_classic() +  

  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1)) +  

  geom_text(x=(repdate-7.5), y=maxn-.5, label="reporting delay*", size=3)
```

[image]

Comment: You either need to remove `expand=c(0,0)` or put the text lower down

Comment: How do I lower the text down?

Comment: Try `y = maxn - 0.75` inside geom text instead of maxn - .5, or other numbers until you are happy with the position.

Comment: Or add the argument vjust = 1 inside geom_text